# How to find a word within text using XSLT 2.0 and REGEX (which doesn't have \b word boundary)?

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-2.0, word-boundary

I am attempting to scan a string of words and look for the presence of a particular word(case insensitive) in an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet using REGEX.

I have a list of words that I wish to iterate over and determine whether or not they exist within a given string.

I want to match on a word anywhere within the given text, but **I do not want to match *within* a word** (i.e. A search for **`foo`** should ***not*** match on "`foo`d" and a search for **`bar`** should ***not*** match on "re`bar`").

XSLT 2.0 REGEX does not have a word boundary(`\b`), so I need to replicate it as best I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use alternation to avoid repetition:

```
<xsl:if test="matches($prose, concat('(^|\W)', $word, '($|\W)'),'i')">
```

Comment: That expression would not compile because XSLT doesn't have non-capturing groups. However, \W is supported and alternate patterns for the first and third group does simplify things nicely. 

The following expression does work: `matches($prose, concat('(^|\W)', $word, '($|\W)'),'i')`

Answer (score 3):

If your XSLT 2.0 processor is Saxon 9 then you can use Java regular expression syntax (including \b) with the functions matches, tokenize and replace by starting the flag attribute with an exclamation mark:

```
<xsl:value-of select="matches('all foo is bar', '\bfoo\b', '!i')"/>
```

Michael Kay mentioned that option recently on the XSL mailing list.

Comment: @Martin - have you gotten it to work? I see that Michael Kay said it is an "undocumented, largely untested, and completely non-conformant option". When I run it against Saxon 9.2.0.3 in oXygen 11 it throws an error:  net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Invalid character '!' in regular expression flags - Invalid character '!' in regular expression flags
Start location: 881:0
URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-xpath-functions-20050211/#ERRFORX0002

Comment: Yes, it works fine for me with Saxon 9.2 HE, tested (now) with both 9.2.0.5 and 9.2.0.3, run from the command line with e.g. java -jar saxon9he.jar. I am not sure why you get that error, but that URL referring to a working draft (WD) version of the XPath functions might indicate you are running an older version of Saxon than you believe.