# What dialect of Regex is in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0

Which [dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) of Regex does XSLT 2.0 use, such as in `<xsl:analyze-string...>`? More specifically, Saxon 9.0.

Or even more to the point: I am not fluent in regex, and want to use a regex tool to develop my XSLT 2.0 regex expressions. But knowing the dialect of regex is prerequisite.

For example, at this [online regex tester](http://www.regexplanet.com/), I'd guess that the XSLT 2.0 regex dialect would be equivalent to either Java or Perl.

**UPDATE**

Cued by replies below, I did more targeted Googling:

- XSLT 2.0 uses Xpath 2.0 regex [spec at w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax). Comment from the spec states infers Perl DNA in the regex, followed by a notable *however* that not all the Perl functions are available:

> The regular expression syntax used by these functions is defined in
>   terms of the regular expression syntax specified in XML Schema (see
>   [XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition]), which in turn is based
>   on the established conventions of languages such as **Perl**. However,
>   because XML Schema uses regular expressions only for validity
>   checking, it omits some facilities that are widely-used with languages
>   such as Perl. This section, therefore, describes extensions to the XML
>   Schema regular expressions syntax that reinstate these capabilities.

- While XSLT 2.0 uses Xpath 2.0 regex, the [spec at w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#regular-expressions) describes enhanced functionality of regex via `<analyze-string>`.

> For more complex string processing than is possible using these
>   functions, XSLT provides an instruction `<analyze-string>` which is
>   defined in this section.

- The W3C Proposed Recommendation for [Xpath 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-analyze-string) contains the addition of `<analyze-string>`
- Interesting for those who use Saxon 9.2 or higher, **Java** syntax might work. See Martin Honnen's comment in this [StackQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397574/how-to-find-a-word-within-text-using-xslt-2-0-and-regex-which-doesnt-have-b-w)
- The Third Party Software section of [Saxon 9.4 documentation](http://www.saxonica.com/download/userdoc94.pdfhttp://www.saxonica.com/download/userdoc94.pdf) notes in table *A6 Regex Translator*:

> net.sf.saxon.java, modules JDK14RegexTranslator and JDK15RegexTranslator, and  net.sf.saxon.dotnet, module DotNetRegexTranslator

**UPDATE 9/14/14** Looks like future Saxons will have a custom regex engine from reworked Jakarta code. [Interesting Read from Michael Kay](http://dev.saxonica.com/blog/mike/2014/02/another-regex-rewrite.html)

Comment: If you are talking about [this regex definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax) then it has it's own dialect which seems to be like JS regex, but without lookahead support, and with better unicode support. Far from Perl regex.

Comment: See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression language in XSLT and XPath 2.0 builds on the one defined in [the W3C schema specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs) and extends it as described in http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#regex-syntax.

Furthermore [the `regex` attribute of `xsl:analyze-string` is an attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string) so you need to pay attention to

> Because the regex attribute is an attribute value template, curly
>   brackets within the regular expression must be doubled. For example,
>   to match a sequence of one to five characters, write regex=".{{1,5}}".
>   For regular expressions containing many curly brackets it may be more
>   convenient to use a notation such as
>   regex="{'[0-9]{1,5}[a-z]{3}[0-9]{1,2}'}", or to use a variable.

Comment: Thanks Martin. See my edited update. I googled a bit and coincidentally found another StackQ by you that stated that Java regex was accessible in Saxon. I altered my code with that in mind: success!